# Generate matrix of bits

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation, octave

I would like to take an integer `n` defining the number of bits in my communication code and a vector defining the alphabet I am assigning to bits `0:n-1`, and output a matrix/cell array containing the alphabetic notation for each state, i.e.:

```
function M = mycommarray(3,[-1,1])
```

produces

```
M = [{-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,1}...]
```

I tried doing this an easier way with `dec2bin(0:7,3)`, but there doesn't seem to be a quick way to make the zeros into `-1`s.

Is there anything close to prepackaged that does this? In this case I don't want anyone to make it for me (related to homework).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dec2bin` is actually not the best way to approach the problem, because its result is an array of strings (*i.e* a matrix of characters), where each digit is a character. If you want `'-1'` to represent a logical "0", that would be two characters, and it introduces problems.

Consider an alternative method with `bitget`. Making use of Shai's suggestion, do the following:

```
[bits, values] = meshgrid(1:3, 0:7);
M = 2 * bitget(values, bits) - 1;
```

The will produce what you want:

```
M =
    -1    -1    -1
     1    -1    -1
    -1     1    -1
     1     1    -1
    -1    -1     1
     1    -1     1
    -1     1     1
     1     1     1
```

Comment: Looks great. It almost broadcasts across the input with ` 2*bitget(101,1:3)-1`, but throws an input size error unless you do it the way you explained.

Comment: Thanks :) the first solution was just something "quick and dirty" to make it work, while I prettied it up with `meshgrid`.

Comment: To put most significant bits on left, like what OP asked in the question, you can use `meshgrid(3:-1:1, 0:7)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To easily convert zeros to `-1` (and leave the ones intact) you can simply do

```
minusOnes = 2 * zeroOnes - 1;
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that, but the output of dec2bin is a 3 digit decimal number, so 101*2-1 becomes 201.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
M = 2 * (dec2bin(0:7, 3)=='1')-1;
```

That returns:

```
M =
    -1    -1    -1
    -1    -1     1
    -1     1    -1
    -1     1     1
     1    -1    -1
     1    -1     1
     1     1    -1
     1     1     1
```

However, it's slower. I get 0.0012s (`dec2bin`) against 0.0002s (`meshgrid`+`bitget`) for 1024 values and 10 bits.