# change dec2bin in matlab to get a logical vector

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a quick way to get a variat of `dec2bin` in Matlab such that it'll return a logical variable vector. For example given a number `n=8` the output will be [1,0,0,0].
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary as double type array, not string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274368/decimal-to-binary-as-double-type-array-not-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply explode the binary representation returned by `dec2bin` (which is already a string!):

```
dec2bin(n) == '1'
```

For `n = 8` this returns a logical vector

```
1     0     0     0
```

This will also work if `n` is a vector of numbers.

Comment: thanks, all the answers work great and all got my +1, I accepted this one because it was the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

Since string '1' is char(49) and string '0' is char(48) you can use:

```
bin = dec2bin(dec) - 48;
```

**This will output the result as an array of doubles**, since you are performing an arithmetic operation over an array (the string coming from «dec2bin» is considered an array in Matlab)

If you want to convert very high integers to binary, I recommend using this code:

```
bin = mod(floor(dec.*2.^-(floor(log2(dec)):-1:0)),2);
```

In order to convert binary vector to decimal:

```
dec = sum(bin.*2.^((length(bin)-1):-1:0));
```

Comment: The solution you recommend for integers is not compatible to integer data types. What is wrong with `bin = dec2bin(dec) - 48;` for large integers?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `dec2bin`, use [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html) instead:

```
bitget(n, fix(log2(n)) + 1:-1:1)
```

**P.S:**
If you have an array of numbers and you want its binary representation as matrix of bits, you might want to take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383415/generate-matrix-of-bits).

#### Example

```
n = 8
b = bitget(n, fix(log2(n)) + 1:-1:1)
```

This results in:

```
b =
     1     0     0     0
```