# How to obtain bits from a file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, bit

I need to encode bits from a file in a signal. Does anyone know how to get the bit representation in a matlab variable? I'd need a vector with each bit of the data.

Using fread to load the data returns a vector with the bytes of the file,i.e., a vector with values between 0 and 255.

Comment: Mmm, the question is similar to the one mentioned but it's different because I'd need to access each bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `dec2bin()`

Like this example

```
dec2bin(23)
Answer :  10111
```

**EDIT**

```
     » dec2bin(0:7) - '0'

   ans =

        0 0 0
        0 0 1
        0 1 0
        0 1 1
        1 0 0
        1 0 1
        1 1 0
        1 1 1
```

Also you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16469761/4385913), and this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16383415/4385913).

Comment: This is useful, thanks ! But how I can get a vector with each digit as component?

Comment: See this [question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/59792)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for [dec2bin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html).

```
>> dec2bin(90)

ans =

1011010
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks ! But how I can get a vector with each digit as component?